# How to fix being unable to see specific category group when category is clicked via drop down box?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to organize the blog categories. I have a few "Test Post" I created and when I start up the server, click on the relevant category tag on the dropdown box the page doesn't show the page relevant to that category. It's not rendering out anything but the header and the sidebar.

## Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from tinymce import HTMLField
from django.utils import timezone

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class CategoryTag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='children'
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',)
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self): 
        full_path = [self.title]

        k = self.parent

        while k is not None:
            full_path.append(k.title)
            k = k.parent

        return ' -> '.join(full_path[::-1])

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overview = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = HTMLField('Content')
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post_img = models.ImageField()
    categories = models.ForeignKey('CategoryTag', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_cat_list(self):           
        k = self.categories
        breadcrumb = ["dummy"]
        while k is not None:
            breadcrumb.append(k.slug)
            k = k.parent

        for i in range(len(breadcrumb)-1):
            breadcrumb[i] = '/'.join(breadcrumb[-1:i-1:-1])
        return breadcrumb[-1:0:-1]

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={
            'id': self.id
        })
```

## Views.py

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
from marketing.models import Signup

def search(request):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(overview__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
    context = {
        'queryset': queryset
    }
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)

def get_category_count():
    queryset = Post  \
        .objects  \
        .values('categories__title')  \
        .annotate(Count('categories__title'))  
    return queryset


def index(request):
    category_count = get_category_count()
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    featured = Post.objects.filter(featured=True)
    latest = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[0:3]
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 6)
    page_request_var = 'page'
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try: 
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST["email"]
        new_signup = Signup()
        new_signup.email = email
        new_signup.save()

    context = {
        'object_list': featured,
        'queryset': paginated_queryset,
        'most_recent': most_recent,
        'latest': latest,
        'page_request_var': page_request_var,
        'category_count': category_count
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def blog_single(request):
    category_count = get_category_count()
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    latest = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'most_recent': most_recent,
        'latest': latest,
        'category_count': category_count
    }
    return render(request, 'blog-single.html', {})

def about(request):
    category_count = get_category_count()
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    latest = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'most_recent': most_recent,
        'latest': latest,
        'category_count': category_count
    }
    return render(request, 'about.html', context)

def category(request):
    return render(request, 'category.html', {})

def contact(request):
    category_count = get_category_count()
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    latest = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    context = {
        'most_recent': most_recent,
        'latest': latest,
        'category_count': category_count
    }
    return render(request, 'contact.html', context)

def post(request, id):
    category_count = get_category_count()
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    latest = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'most_recent': most_recent,
        'latest': latest,
        'category_count': category_count
    }
    return render(request, 'blog-single.html', context)

def show_category(request,hierarchy= None):
    category_slug = hierarchy.split('/')
    category_queryset = list(CategoryTag.objects.all())
    all_slugs = [ x.slug for x in category_queryset ]
    parent = None
    for slug in category_slug:
        if slug in all_slugs:
            parent = get_object_or_404(CategoryTag,slug=slug,parent=parent)
        else:
            instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
            breadcrumbs_link = instance.get_cat_list()
            category_name = [' '.join(i.split('/')[-1].split('-')) for i in breadcrumbs_link]
            breadcrumbs = zip(breadcrumbs_link, category_name)
            return render(request, "blog-single.html", {'instance':instance,'breadcrumbs':breadcrumbs})

    return render(request,"category.html",{'post_set':parent.post_set.all(),'sub_categories':parent.children.all()})
```

## Urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings 
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from post import views


from post.views import index, blog_single, about, category, post, search, contact

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')), # new
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), # new
    path('blog_single/', blog_single),
    path('about/', about),
    path('category/', category),
    path('search', search, name='search'),
    path('post/<id>/', post, name='post-detail'),
    path('contact/', contact),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.blog_single, name="detail"),
    path(r'^category/(?P<hierarchy>.+)/$', views.show_category, name='category') 
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## category.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<section class="site-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            {% if sub_categories %}
              <h2 class="mb-4">Sub Categories</h2>
              {% for i in sub_categories %}
                <a href="{{ i.slug }}"> {{ i.name }} </a>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row blog-entries">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 main-content">
            <div class="row mb-5 mt-5">
              <div class="col-md-12">
              {% if post_set %}
              {% for i in post_set %}
                <div class="post-entry-horzontal">
                  <a href="{{ i.slug }}">
                    <div class="image element-animate" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" style="background-image: url(images/img_10.jpg);">
                    </div>
                    <span class="text">
                      <div class="post-meta">
                        <span class="category">{{ i.slug }}</span>
                        <span class="mr-2">{{ obj.timestamp|timesince }} ago </span> &bullet;
                        <span class="ml-2"><span class="fa fa-comments"></span> {{ post.comment_count }}</span>
                      </div>
                      <h2>{{ i.title | truncatechars:30}}</h2>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </div>     
              {% endfor %}  
              {% endif %}
                              <!-- END post -->
                              <!-- END post -->
              </div>
            </div>
              <!-- Pagination -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <nav aria-label="Page navigation" class="text-center">
                  <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item  active"><a class="page-link" href="#">Prev</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- END main-content -->

          {% include 'sidebar.html' with category_count=category_count most_recent=most_recent %}

          <!-- END sidebar -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
{% endblock %}
```